# Duplicate User appears in TFS work item query. :1 postfix

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, team-foundation-server, visual-studio

One of our developers appears twice when trying ot assign work items in TFS2010.  Once appears normally as jsmith and then another shows up as DOMAIN\jsmith:1.

There is only one user by this name in the Active directory and only one shows up when running the following command:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio10.0\Common7\IDE>tfssecurity.exe/imx all: /server:http://TFS1:8080/tfs

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2.
SW: Team Foundation Server 2010.
WS: Windows 7 Business X64.

Is there any way for me to get rid of this ghost user?  I've been stuck on this problem for ages now.  Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate names in a domain, TFS addes domain\user to disambiguate. Maybe look again at the user in AD, paying close attention to any potential aliases for jsmith, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim,

There are certainly no duplicate entries in the AD at present.  It is possible that user jsmith was deleted and then re-added.  Could this have caused it?  And if so, is there any way to check?  And any way to fix it?

Cheers